# How to replace all numbers that don't have quotes with numbers having quotes

Tags: java, replace

I have a web service that returns data in the form of json. but the returned data actually not in json format because for some key values like ids it gives the values of numbers without any quotes because of that when I am creating an object it throws an exception so my requirement is simple how can i surround quotes to the numbers that don't have quotes.

```
{"name":"pragnani","job":"android developer","experience":"fresher","age":22,"id":10}
```

Here Id and age are not there with quotes, I want to replace them with quotes.
Don't simple post substring kind of a thing because it won't work because web services return huge amount of data . And I am using one separate class to retrive data from different web services .so Please help me....

Edit:
Here is the data

```
"[{\"PracticeID\":36,\"PracticeName\":\"Dr. John Doe\",\"DBServerName\":\"DBSERVER8\"}]"
```

this is the method to retrive data

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
    String results="";
    try {
             HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpPost post = new HttpPost(aurl[0]);
             post.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
                 StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(dto.toString());
                 post.setEntity(entity);
                 HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(post);
                 String respStr = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
                 results=respStr.trim();
                 results=results.replace("]\"", "]").replace("}", "\"}").replace("\":", "\":\"").replace("}\",","},");
                 results=results.replace("\"[", "[");
                 results=results.replace("\\\"", "\"");
                 results=results.replace("\"\"", "\"");    

                 String[] arr=results.split("\\{");
                 if(arr.length<=2)
                 {
                     results=results.substring(results.indexOf("[")+1,results.indexOf("]"));
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     results=results.replace("[", "{\"result\":[").replace("]", "]}");
                 }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return results;
}
```

How to I convert it into json String....

Comment: Why do you want them as strings? Aren't they numeric in nature?

Comment: Why can't you fix the output so it produces JSon, instead of a work around?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I have got the web services from the client...I was not there in a position to talk with my TL about this...so need to solve it ..thanks for reply

Comment: Uh, your input is valid JSON. Are you perhaps trying to map the numbers to Strings?

Comment: Alternatively, JSON has a floating point type, so what about adding a dot to the end of each number?

Comment: @Nambari When I try to create the Json object from the json string it throws exception

Comment: @Pragnani - include in your question, the object you are trying to map this JSON to.

Comment: @Makoto I was wrong......you are correct.. I was getting exception not because of numbers don't have quotes, but because of unterminated " quote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON allows numeric values in its structure (I.E. unquoted numbers). They can be intergers floats or any other numeric type that JavaScript would recognize.

Allowed types: Objects, Arrays, Numerics, Strings, Booleans, null.

As opposed to normal JavaScript all Object keys have to be quoted, that is true! Asides from that you can directly use numerics at will.

Comment: But when I try to use in my android project it throws JSONException

Comment: Did you get an exception message? Or a code? Post that exception message/code in your question or in a separate question so we can find the true cause of your problem.

Comment: For me, copy-pasting your exact string into my FireBug console creates a perfectly valid object with accessible properties (including the numeric ones).

Comment: Actually it is mid night in India I was not in office...I'll edit and update the code tomorrow.....sorry for this excuse

Comment: Yeah.....you are correct.. I was getting exception not because of numbers don't have quotes, but because of unterminated " quote